# when exactly does a while loop stop in java?

Tags: java, loops

What exact moment does a while loop stop? for example:

```
int a = 0;
int b = 1;
int c = 2;
int d = 1;
boolean destroyTheEarth = false;
while (a == 0) {
   if (b == 1){
       if (c == 1){
          a = 0;
       }else{
          a = 1;
       }
   }else{
       d = 0;
   }
   if (d == 0){
       destroyTheEarth = true;
   }else{
       destroyTheEarth = false;
   }
}
```

Will the earth be destroyed in this code or will the loop exit the moment a is set to 1? I tried to search around but every example I found wasn't exactly like this so I wasn't certain. Because of that I figured i'd ask to be sure.

Comment: second if condition is out of the while loop is it intentionally or by mistake?

Comment: its not a do while loop, its just a while loop. Sorry I didn't realize the title could be interpreted as that. I guess the title should be: What exact moment does a "while" loop stop?

Comment: @H B, I'm not sure what you mean, everything after "while (a == 0) is in the loop.

Comment: then you need to put {} after while loop

Comment: Use braces and I think it will be clear. Indentation does not control membership of a statement.

Comment: use Curly braces in your while loop and if else conditions

Comment: @H B, Sorry, I know that I just intentionally left that out to save time. This code isn't real im not using it for anything i just made it up on the spot as an example for what I was thinking about. The point is about when would the loop end.

Comment: @narwhalrus97 No, it's not because you didn't surround you while loop with curly braces. The last if-else is outside the while loop

Comment: @narwhalrus97 it changes the meaning of code...

Comment: @PrzemysławMoskal My apologies I left out the curly braces to save time I assumed it was implied that everything was in the loop but that was dumb of me. it was edited it so it should be good now.

Comment: This is not python where indention consider as block.

Comment: @HB, yes my fault, I assumed people would assume that the whole code was in the while loop but that was dumb of me. It was edited so it should be fixed now.

Comment: @narwhalrus97 As par your code loop will execute once and then terminate with destroyTheEarth  = false.

Comment: @narwhalrus97 I assume you want to know for all loops in general... All the code in the while loop will be executed, and then it goes back up top where it checks the conditional. If the conditional is true, it enters and goes through everything again. If not, it just skips the while loop and moves on with the code after. The only time a program would exit in the middle of a while loop is if there is a break statement, or if there's an exception being thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Condition in first `if` statement `(b==0)` is true, so `else` assigning 0 to `d` will never be done. So when you go to the next `if` statement and check if `d==0`,you know it's false. This means the code included in last `else` will be executed and false will be assigned to `destroyEarth`.

Answer (score 0):

Under normal circumstances, a `while` loop stops when either:

1. **prior to** the execution of the body, the `while` condition is `false`, OR
2. A `break` statement is executed within the body (as long as that `break` isn't in the body of another loop nested within the this one...)

Once the decision to execute the loop body has been made, the body executes in its entirety.  Only then does the `while` statement evaluate its condition again and decide whether or not to execute the loop another time.

If you want to prevent part of the body from executing when the loop condition is no longer true, you have to put code in the body to do that.

In your example, then, Earth's fate hangs in the balance on *every* trip around the loop.  Merely setting `a = 1` in the middle of what will ultimately be the loop's final iteration doesn't magically stop the loop then and there---unless you program that magic yourself.  You have a couple of choices.

1) guard that last fate-deciding `if` with another `if` that only lets it execute when the loop condition is still true:

```
while (a==0){
    ...
    if (a==0) { is 'while' condition still true?
        if (d == 0){
           destroyTheEarth = true;
       }else{
           destroyTheEarth = false;
       }
    }
}
```

2) add a`break` statement immediately after setting `a = 1` to end the loop immediately:

```
while (a == 0) {
   if (b == 1){
       if (c == 1){
          a = 0;
       }else{
          a = 1;
          break;
       }
   }
   ...
}
```